# Xcode Cross Compiling cocos2d Errors

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cross-compiling

When i try to compile my project for the simulator or real devices, i get these errors:

```
Ld /Users/maumau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HarvestMoon-bciczopagtmfyqgxjxasrffzrnls/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HarvestMoon.app/HarvestMoon normal armv7
cd /Users/maumau/Dropbox/Daten/Projekte/HMiOS
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -L/Users/maumau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HarvestMoon-bciczopagtmfyqgxjxasrffzrnls/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/maumau/Dropbox/Daten/Projekte/HMiOS/../../../../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HarvestMoon-bciczopagtmfyqgxjxasrffzrnls/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/maumau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HarvestMoon-bciczopagtmfyqgxjxasrffzrnls/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/maumau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HarvestMoon-bciczopagtmfyqgxjxasrffzrnls/Build/Intermediates/HarvestMoon.build/Debug-iphoneos/HarvestMoon.build/Objects-normal/armv7/HarvestMoon.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 /Users/maumau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HarvestMoon-bciczopagtmfyqgxjxasrffzrnls/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libbox2d.a -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/maumau/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HarvestMoon-bciczopagtmfyqgxjxasrffzrnls/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HarvestMoon.app/HarvestMoon

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCRepeatForever", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in KBPlayer.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCTMXTiledMap", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_KBTMXTiledMap in KBTMXTiledMap.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCDirector", referenced from:
.... more errors ....

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i use Xcode 4.2 and cocos2d-1.0. does anyone have an idea, how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to make sure that your project includes cocos2d source code or cocos2d static library. If you are using cocos2d static library, it must be compiled for armv7.

Your project is based on [cocos2d application template](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/resources%3atemplates)?